# How do I connect Ubuntu server 20.04 to WIFI?

Tags: networking, server, wireless

This is my first time trying to start a server and I am having issues connecting Ubuntu Server to wifi. I followed a lot of YouTube videos and tutorials and none of them seem to work. All of the videos I have seen just show people connecting to ethernet or they already somehow have their networks connected automatically from install.

I tried to go into /etc/netplan/ and change the yaml file but it does not show anything there, it is just empty. All the other tutorials tell me to use some ip configuration commands to change the network settings but they all have to be downloaded from the internet.

How would I connect to my wifi in Ubuntu Server?